# Resource files are case sensitive on production server?

Tags: ee2, url, htaccess

This seems so basic, but how would I make all of my URL's case insensitive? On my dev, everything worked fine, but on production, images are broken, resources are 404, etc.

I know I could do something like this:

```
RewriteMap tolowercase int:tolower 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${tolowercase:$1}
```

But I don't want to need to rename all of my files.

*** EDIT ***

I have just renamed my files since I couldn't find a solution yet. The odd thing is that I even had to modify an add-on: acc.theeditorcodemirror.php line 74

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("select * from exp_TECM_settings where member_id = '".$this->EE->db->escape_str($this->EE->session->userdata('member_id'))."'");
```

had to be changed to:

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("select * from exp_tecm_settings where member_id = '".$this->EE->db->escape_str($this->EE->session->userdata('member_id'))."'");
```

Comment: It is server settings, not EE. You local machine possible is Windows, but on server you have *nix.

Comment: Max - You are right. I forgot about that when I worked on this one on a PC and not my MBP. I didn't think about that mattering since I was using WAMP. The only thing that bothered me is that even the addon had to be modified. I hadn't ever had to do that before.

Comment: same story: Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix. Because databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: Thanks Max... If you want to add your notes as an answer, I'll accept them and close this out.   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on unix system files is always case sensitive (instead of Window). It possible to make some settings for apache to make filesystem case insensitive but it is not right.
Same story with db name:

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on
>   the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the
>   underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of
>   database and table names. This means database and table names are not
>   case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of
>   Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS X, which is Unix-based but uses
>   a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive.